# Radio Buttons are not working on ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am trying to use Native-Base radio buttons. I've added some additional code to it for making radio buttons work. While it's still not working. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, ListItem, Text, Radio, Right } from 'native-base';
export default class RadioButtonExample extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   itemSelected: 'itemOne',
 }
}
render() {
 return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>Daily Stand Up</Text>
          <Right>
            <Radio onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: 'itemOne' })}
              selected={this.state.itemSelected == 'itemOne'}
            />
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>Discussion with Client</Text>
          <Right>
            <Radio onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: 'itemTwo' })}
                  selected={this.state.itemSelected == 'itemTwo' }
                />
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
      </Content>
    </Container>
   );
  }
}
```

How can this code be fixed? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the onPress event in the ListItem

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, ListItem, Text, Radio, Right } from "native-base";

export default class RadioButtonExample extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      itemSelected: "itemOne",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <ListItem onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: "itemOne" })}>
            <Text>Daily Stand Up</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={this.state.itemSelected == "itemOne"} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem onPress={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: "itemTwo" })}>
            <Text>Discussion with Client</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={this.state.itemSelected == "itemTwo"} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The issue with this code is that when you run an app both radio buttons are turned off while by default first one should be turned on.

Comment: @NewTechLover did you find any solution for this?